# Why can't I convert my py file into .exe files with multiple errors

Tags: python, pyautogui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoYY5.png)

Basically it is just a bunch of autohotkey script in python. Nothing fancy I am just a beginner who is trying to learn python. The script ran just fine in pycharm but when i converted it to exe file those errors showed up.

Anyone can help me out? I mean it is not important since I can just run it fine on pycharm but it would be nice if I am able to made it into a exe file.

```
import time
import ImageChops
from ahk import AHK
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image ,ImageChops

ahk = AHK()
win = ahk.active_window
win = ahk.find_window(title=b'Roblox')

#need to change food and drink position location


def check_loading():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    img = pyautogui.screenshot('screenloading.png', region=(500, 700, 200, 150))
    time.sleep(1)
    img1 = Image.open('screenloading.png')
    img2 = Image.open('loading.png')
    diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)
    if diff.getbbox():
        print('\nno loading screen detected')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return True
    else:
        ahk.mouse_move(x=933, y=640, speed=10)
        time.sleep(3)
        print('sleeped\n')
        return False

def check_cheque():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    img = pyautogui.screenshot('screen.png', region=(725, 550, 400, 120))
    time.sleep(1)
    img1 = Image.open('screen.png')
    img2 = Image.open('cheque.png')
    diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)
    if diff.getbbox():
        return False
    else:
        ahk.mouse_move(x=933, y=640, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        return True

def loading():
    while check_loading() == False:
        check_loading()
        if check_loading() == True:
            print('done loading\n')
            break

def return_position():
    ahk.mouse_move(x=937, y=1017, speed=10)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=762, y=755, speed=10)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=865, y=713, speed=10)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1024, y=656, speed=10)
    ahk.click()

    time.sleep(3)
    loading()
    ahk.key_up('s')
    ahk.key_down('s')
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.key_up('s')
    loading()
    time.sleep(0.3)

def school():
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(2)
    ahk.key_up('w')

    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    ahk.key_down('a')
    time.sleep(2.5)
    ahk.key_up('a')


    time.sleep(1)

    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(1.7)
    ahk.key_up('w')


    time.sleep(1)

    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=906, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')

    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(3)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    loading()

def pet_sleep():
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1341, y=619, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1354, y=648, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(35)

    #food
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1341, y=619, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1354, y=648, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1283, y=576, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1166, y=576, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1108, y=705, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    #drink
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1341, y=619, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1354, y=648, speed=20)
    ahk.click()

    ahk.mouse_move(x=1247, y=583, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1101, y=867, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1163, y=860, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(3)



def school_sleep():

    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(0.9)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.key_up('d')
    ahk.key_down('d')
    time.sleep(1.76)
    ahk.key_up('d')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ahk.key_up('w')


    ahk.mouse_move(x=998, y=478, speed=10)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=998, y=455, speed=10)
    ahk.click()
    pet_sleep()
    time.sleep(1)



def camp_fire():
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')

    time.sleep(2.2)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_up('d')
    ahk.key_down('d')

    time.sleep(3)
    ahk.key_up('d')
    time.sleep(0.5)


    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=983, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')

    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(10.7)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    ahk.key_down('a')
    time.sleep(12.5)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    time.sleep(0.5)

    ahk.key_down('w')
    ahk.key_down('Space')
    time.sleep(10   )
    ahk.key_up('Space')
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.5)

    ahk.key_down('a')
    time.sleep(1)
    ahk.key_up('a')

    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.5)

def camp_sleep():
    ahk.mouse_move(x=614, y=574, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=617, y=544, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(60)

def hot_spring():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(2)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    ahk.key_down('a')
    time.sleep(3)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    time.sleep(0.5)

    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=895, y=506, speed=10)
    time.sleep(0.4)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(15)
    ahk.key_up('w')


def playground():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(2)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    ahk.key_down('a')
    time.sleep(3)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    time.sleep(0.5)

    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=895, y=506, speed=10)
    time.sleep(0.4)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(11.3)
    ahk.key_up('w')

    time.sleep(0.4)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=974, y=506, speed=10)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(8.3)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.4)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.3)

    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=949, y=506, speed=10)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    ahk.key_down('space')
    time.sleep(8.4)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_up('space')
    time.sleep(0.1)


def heal():

    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=20)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=20)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(2.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ahk.key_up('d')
    ahk.key_down('d')
    time.sleep(3.3)
    ahk.key_up('d')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(4.3)
    ahk.key_up('w')

    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    ahk.mouse_move(x=963, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(2.3)
    ahk.key_up('w')

    time.sleep(2)
    loading()

    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(1.1)
    ahk.key_up('w')

    ahk.mouse_move(x=941, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')

    ahk.mouse_move(x=969, y=506, speed=10)
    ahk.key_down('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ahk.key_up('LSHIFT')
    time.sleep(0.2)

    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(2)
    ahk.key_up('w')

    ahk.key_up('a')
    ahk.key_down('a')
    time.sleep(0.12)
    ahk.key_up('a')
    time.sleep(0.1)

    ahk.key_up('w')
    ahk.key_down('w')
    time.sleep(1.9)
    ahk.key_up('w')
    time.sleep(1)


    ahk.mouse_move(x=1642, y=861, speed=30)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1007, y=652, speed=30)
    ahk.click()
    time.sleep(2)



def check_ailments():

    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    pyautogui.screenshot('ailment.png', region=(650, 20, 500, 87))
    imgl = Image.open('ailment.png')
    imgl.show()

    # check for ailments
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('food.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('food found')
        food = False
    else:
        print('food not found')
        food = False


    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('drink.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('drink found')
        drink = False
    else:
        print('drink not found')
        drink = False


    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('sleep.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('sleep found')
        sleep = True
    else:
        print('sleep not found')
        sleep = False


    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('hotspring.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('hotspring found')
        hotspringg = True
    else:
        print('hotspring not found')
        hotspringg = False

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('heal.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('heal found')
        heall = True
    else:
        print('heal not found')
        heall = False

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('school.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('school found')
        schooll = True
    else:
        print('school not found')
        schooll = False


    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('play.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('play found')
        play = True
    else:
        print('play not found')
        play = False

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('camping.png', confidence=0.9):
        print('camping found')
        camping = True
    else:
        print('camping not found')
        camping = False



    ahk.mouse_move(x=1825, y=13, speed=20)  # close the picture
    ahk.click()
    ahk.mouse_move(x=1623, y=553, speed=11)
    check_cheque()

    if food == True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ahk.mouse_move(x=932, y=997, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ahk.mouse_move(x=736, y=826, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=1078, y=695, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=1161, y=785, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=25, y=581, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.mouse_move(x=932, y=997, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=1380, y=677, speed=10)
        food = False
        check_cheque()
    if drink == True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ahk.mouse_move(x=940, y=1003, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=739, y=829, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=1102, y=872, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=1207, y=965, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=25, y=581, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)
        ahk.click()
        time.sleep(1.6)

        ahk.mouse_move(x=932, y=997, speed=10)
        ahk.click()
        ahk.mouse_move(x=1380, y=677, speed=10)
        check_cheque()
        drink = False


    #hotspring
    if hotspringg == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        hot_spring()
        time.sleep(60)
        hotspringg = False

    #heal
    if heall == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        heal()
        check_cheque()
        heall = False

    #school
    if schooll == True & sleep == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        school()
        check_cheque()
        school_sleep()
        check_cheque()
        schooll = False
        sleep = False

    elif schooll == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        school()
        check_cheque()
        schooll = False
        time.sleep(60)

    #play ground
    if play == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        playground()
        check_cheque()
        play = False
        time.sleep(60)

    #camping
    if camping == True & sleep == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        camp_fire()
        check_cheque()
        camp_sleep()
        check_cheque()
        camping = False
        sleep = False
    elif camping == True:
        check_cheque()
        return_position()
        check_cheque()
        camp_fire()
        check_cheque()
        camping = False
        time.sleep(60)

    if camping == False & play == False & heall == False & hotspringg == False & schooll == False & sleep == False & food == False & drink == False:
        print("\nno ailment detected waiting for ailment")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("waiting for ailment \n")
        time.sleep(5)
    elif camping == False & play == False & heall == False & hotspringg == False & schooll == False & sleep == False & food == True & drink == True:
        print("\nFood and drinks are disabled")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("waiting for ailment\n")
        time.sleep(5)
    elif camping == False & play == False & heall == False & hotspringg == False & schooll == False & sleep == False & food == False & drink == True:
        print("\n drinks are disabled")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("waiting for ailment\n")
        time.sleep(5)
    elif camping == False & play == False & heall == False & hotspringg == False & schooll == False & sleep == False & food == True & drink == False:
        print("\n Foods are disabled")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("waiting for ailment\n")
        time.sleep(5)

def starting():

    if win.exist:
        print('Roblox detected')
    else:
        exit(0)
    while win.active != True:
        print('Roblox is not active waiting for 10 seconds\n')
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        print('roblox is active')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print('running ailments\n')
        check_cheque()
        check_ailments()

time.sleep(1)

print("Welcome to adopt python autofarm")
print("__________________________________")
time.sleep(0.4)
user = input("\nPress enter to proceed\n")
while win:
    starting()
```

Comment: Wrapping a Python program in an executable is considerably more complex than you seem to imagine. The `pyinstaller` documentation has a very useful section called *When things go wrong*. But it is not addressed to Python novices. The *only* reason to build an executable is because you want to deploy your application to other users that do not have Python installed. Such `.exe` files are very big and take a long time to load. You don't have to run your program "inside PyCharm." To run from the command line, instead of doing `myapp.exe`, do `python myapp.py` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will keep it in .py then. Though I am curious about the .exe format but I will try to learn more about python before touching that.